# Got 'Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException' and the data is not added to the database

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a telegram bot that can accept words and save them to a database (in the future I want to convert this into an assistant for learning words in Spanish)

There was a problem with the fact that when the method is called again to add words, an Exception occurs in thread Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

My code for DB connection and adding words:

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager



object SQLiteConnection {
    private var connection: Connection? = null

    fun connect(databasePath: String) {
        val url = "jdbc:sqlite:$databasePath"
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
            println("Connection to SQLite has been established.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    }

    fun getConnection(): Connection? {
        return connection
    }

    fun closeConnection() {
        try {
            connection?.close()
            println("DB connection was closed")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    }
fun addWord(wordCategoryId: Int, inSpanish: String, inRussian: String){
        connection?.use { conn ->
            val statement = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO Words (word_category_id, in_spanish, in_russian) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            )
            statement.setInt(1, wordCategoryId)
            statement.setString(2, inSpanish)
            statement.setString(3, inRussian)
            println("Word added to the database: $inRussian, $inSpanish, $wordCategoryId")
            statement.executeUpdate()
        }
    }
```

And code in main:

```
import DB.SQLiteConnection
import Users.UserManager
import Users.greetingMessageForUser
import com.github.kotlintelegrambot.bot
import com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatch
import com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.command
import com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.text
import com.github.kotlintelegrambot.entities.ChatId

fun main() {
    val databasePath = "C:\\sqlite\\spanish.db"
    SQLiteConnection.connect(databasePath)
    SQLiteConnection.createTables()


    val userManager = UserManager()

    val bot = bot {
        token = "TOKEN"

        dispatch {
            command("start") {
                println("Received /start command")
                val user = userManager.getUserInfo(message)
                println("User ID: ${user.id}, Username: ${user.username}, First Name: ${user.firstName}, Last Name: ${user.lastName}")
                bot.sendMessage(ChatId.fromId(message.chat.id), text = greetingMessageForUser(user.firstName))
                bot.sendMessage(ChatId.fromId(message.chat.id), text = "Пока доступны следующие команды: Добавление слова в БД: /addWord.)
                SQLiteConnection.addUser(user.id,user.username, user.firstName, user.lastName)


            }
               command("addWord") {
                   bot.sendMessage(
                       ChatId.fromId(message.chat.id),
                       text = "Введите русское слово:"
                   )
                   text {
                       val russianWord = text ?: "Empty message"
                       println("Received message: $russianWord")
                       SQLiteConnection.addWord(1, "qwe", russianWord)
                       println("Word $russianWord was added to DB")
                       bot.sendMessage(ChatId.fromId(message.chat.id), text = "Слово $russianWord добавлено в базу. Продолжите вводить слова, чтобы добавлять их в БД. Чтобы прекратить, нажмите /stopAdd")
                   }
               }

        }
    }
    bot.startPolling()
}
```

After starting the program, I can add one word, but when I click on /start again, the error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:756)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:778)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:170)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:194)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:169)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:194)
    at com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.Dispatcher.handleUpdate(Dispatcher.kt:97)
    at com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.Dispatcher.checkQueueUpdates(Dispatcher.kt:40)
    at com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.Dispatcher.access$checkQueueUpdates(Dispatcher.kt:17)
    at com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.Dispatcher$checkQueueUpdates$1.invokeSuspend(Dispatcher.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@32d3b4a0, java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService@5deb4038]
```

I tried opening and closing the DB connection in each method, but it didn't help

Dispatcher class:

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher

public final class Dispatcher internal constructor(updatesChannel: kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.types.DispatchableObject>, logLevel: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.logging.LogLevel, coroutineDispatcher: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher) {
    internal final lateinit var bot: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.Bot /* compiled code */

    private final val commandHandlers: kotlin.collections.LinkedHashSet<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.Handler> /* = java.util.LinkedHashSet<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.Handler> */ /* compiled code */

    private final val errorHandlers: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.ErrorHandler> /* = java.util.ArrayList<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.ErrorHandler> */ /* compiled code */

    private final var job: kotlinx.coroutines.Job? /* compiled code */

    private final val logLevel: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.logging.LogLevel /* compiled code */

    private final val scope: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope /* compiled code */

    private final val updatesChannel: kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel<com.github.kotlintelegrambot.types.DispatchableObject> /* compiled code */

    public final fun addErrorHandler(errorHandler: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.ErrorHandler): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    public final fun addHandler(handler: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.Handler): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    private final suspend fun checkQueueUpdates(): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    private final fun handleError(error: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.errors.TelegramError): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    private final suspend fun handleUpdate(update: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.entities.Update): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    public final fun removeErrorHandler(errorHandler: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.ErrorHandler): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    public final fun removeHandler(handler: com.github.kotlintelegrambot.dispatcher.handlers.Handler): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    internal final fun startCheckingUpdates(): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    internal final fun stopCheckingUpdates(): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the `Dispatcher` class? According to stacktrace, problem happens somewhere there, not in the provided code.

Comment: @broot, added to the question. But im not sure i got you correctly

Comment: Ahh, ok, I thought this is your code. I don't know this telegram bot library, so I won't help you, but the error happens inside that lib. That means one of two things: a bug in the library, so I suggest updating it to the latest. Or incorrect use of this lib. It looks like it tried adding a new command handler while commands were already being processed and that caused the error.